# How to use multiple theme in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

**Scenario :**

As a beginner of Angular 2, I am creating an application
 having two diffent areas.

- Admin and
- Customers.

  For both of these areas I want to use two different themes.

  *E.g. "Admin LTE" for Admin area and One custom theme for Customer area.*

**Problem :**

- How to handle their different css and js using angular-cli.json
- How can I use them in index.html?

Answer (score 1):

I also having the same question for my learning purpose blog project.
I have different themes for admin/users. I found something which solve my problem.

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

I used this as following.

#### index.html

```html
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/clean-blog.css">
```

added above line in `index.html`

#### blog.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ProgressbarService, PostService, TitleService } from '../services';
import { Post, User, Comment } from '../models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css']
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document){ }
  // if user switch from admin to blog need to update theme css.
  ngOnInit() {
    this.document.getElementById('theme')
      .setAttribute('href', './assets/css/clean-blog.css');
  }

}
```

#### admin.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'admin.component.html'
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', './assets/css/main.css');
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What if I want to add multiple js files from node_modules?

Comment: If you can get any element by id then you can create elements in DOM also using DOCUMENT. I didn't try but you can try to add js at runtime.

Comment: This have a problem, when the AdminComponent be compile, before that the index,html rendered. so if you modify the html and add or remove something like <link> tag, There will be no effect, so how can we fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You can create two components in your app. Through angular@cli like this:

```
ng g c customers
ng g c admin
```

Now each will create 4 files like this:

```
installing component
  create src\app\customers\customers.component.css
  create src\app\customers\customers.component.html
  create src\app\customers\customers.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\customers\customers.component.ts
  update src\app\app.module.ts
```

and

```
installing component
  create src\app\admin\admin.component.css
  create src\app\admin\admin.component.html
  create src\app\admin\admin.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\admin\admin.component.ts
  update src\app\app.module.ts
```

Now each component/section have there own css file which you can use to create there own custom theme i:e `customers.component.css` and `admin.component.css`

Also read about shadow DOM by searching on google to get more information about the same

Bonus:
Type

```
ng g c customers --spec false
```

or

```
ng g c admin --spec false
```

this will not create the .spec.ts file which is only for testing purpose.